# How can an image be saved with JavaScript for Automator (JXA) in macOS Preview application?

Tags: javascript, macos, automator, macos-mojave, javascript-automation

There is an image open in the Preview application, and it is unsaved.

I have tried this code, by building and running a standalone script in Script Editor:

```
var preview = Application('Preview')
var preview.documents[0].close({ saving: true, savingIn: '/Volumes/USB Drive/Untitled-Image.png' })
```

I see this in the logs

```
app = Application("Preview")
    app.documents.at(0).Symbol.toPrimitive()
        --> Error -1700: Can't convert types.
    app.documents.at(0).Symbol.toPrimitive()
        --> Error -1700: Can't convert types.
```

However, I'm not sure I'm reading the docs correctly, and I'm not sure how to further debug this code.   A satisfactory alternative here would be to send a keystroke to save and click the Save button.

What can I do to persist the image in Preview to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can declare paths speculatively in JavaScript using `Path('...')`, and then use the `save` command to save the image to the file that will be created at that path:

```
Preview = Application('com.apple.Preview');
ImageFilepath = Path('/Users/CK/Pictures/Preview_SavedImage.jpg');
Preview.documents[0].save({ in: ImageFilepath });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  This code fails with "Script Error:  Error on line 3: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ImageFile". Fixing the variable, it fails with: 'The document "Untitled" could not be saved as "Preview_SavedImage.jpg". The file doesn't exist.' I suspect this works with a file that is already saved, but would be glad to see an example with the save method that will save an open file.

Comment: The first error is a typo on my part, which it sounds like you managed to workaround my tardiness in this instance. The second error ought not to occur; as stated, the filepaths can be speculative (i.e. not yet in existence), and I tested the code in order to save a new image created from the clipboard and written out to a new file. Can you supply the script you used to generate the error please ?

Comment: The script was this exact code - which was the problem. The directory does not exist on my machine. :facepalm: Too bad the error message doesn't state that instead.

Comment: LOLZ. I suspected something like that, but not quite so...overt. My assumption was that you had used a tilde in the filepath, which I believe generates the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
var preview = Application('Preview')
var photo = preview.documents[0]
photo.close({ saving: 'yes', savingIn: Path("/Path/To Some/file_name.png") })
```

Upon execution, in the Replies log of Script Editor window, something slightly different from the question sample is logged.

```
app = Application("Preview")
    app.close(app.documents.at(0), {savingIn:Path("/Path/To Some/file_name.png"), saving:"yes"})
```

I was able to figure this out by studying the [scripting dictionary](https://support.apple.com/guide/script-editor/view-an-apps-scripting-dictionary-scpedt1126/mac) for macOS Mojave 10.14 as well as the [Release Notes for JXA](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html); there is a similar example under [Passing Event Modifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW36) section of that.

From the Script Editor scripting dictionaries, this is the entry for the `close` method in the Standard Suite:

```
close method : Close a document.
  close specifier : the document(s) or window(s) to close.
    [saving: "yes"/‌"no"/‌"ask"] : Should changes be saved before closing?
    [savingIn: File] : The file in which to save the document, if so.
```

Note the key differences between the working code here and the code in the question:

1. Specify a [Path object](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW31) when passing the `savingIn` option to `close`.
2. Specify a the saving option as one of "yes", "no", or "ask" (not `true`).

If you're new to JXA, Automator, and/or Script Editor for Mac, checkout the [JXA Cookbook](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook).

If this answer helps you, you're probably having a bad time, so best of luck!